# uiautomator viewer error while trying to take the screenshot of the emulator screen or either the device connected

Tags: android, testing, ui-automation, appium-android

Anyone can please provide me a better solution for the errors I am 
    mentioning down.As i have already tried so many solutions from 
    every 
    possible website.
    [Refer the image and please help me with the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7eVg.png)

Comment: I fixed the same issue by using following methods.

(1) Connect your Android device to your development machines;

(2) Go to command line in terminal or DOS command line for Windows;

(3) Using "adb shell" into your Android devices;

(4) Change the user to root by input "su root" in command line;

(5) Change the access right to /data/local/tmp by input "chmod 777 /data/local/tmp";

(6) Go back to uiautomatorviewer and do screen shot again, the error should be gone;

I guess there are some file can't be access if it doesn't own right in /data/local/tmp.

Comment: while using adb shell command it is showing me ,that adb server out of date killing ....

Comment: which version sdk you used?

Comment: and i am using linux actually.What i need to change can u pls brief me .So,i will try that in linux

Comment: min sdk version is 15

Comment: pls update latest sdk platform tools and try with 1) sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
2)
"sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb"

this code.

Comment: This solutions is not working

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an active Appium connection to the device.
When you have an active Appium connection to your device / emulator, it will lock the ui-automator resources. So you will not be able to take a snapshot at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you run below commands from terminal before taking screenshots.

```
adb root
adb remount
```

This fixed the issue for me. Also make sure a test is not already running on the device.